# CellList infinite scrolling

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

From the showcase demo, `ShowMorePagerPanel`, I can see this line

```
display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize);
```

Does that mean each time we scroll, all item from 0 up to `max` will keep on repeatedly being retrieved and displayed?  How can we make it only retrieve subsequent new items and use the cache for all previous old items (starting from 0)?  Is this possible?  Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize)` will show all till the reached maximum. That is indeed the purpose of ShowMorePagerPanel

For what you want, if I understood you correctly, you just need something like `display.setVisibleRange(newPageSize - incrementSize, newPageSize)`

However I guess that's gonna be a weird user interface. If you just need to show X elements at a time, better use simply a table with X visible elements and then add in the interface a navigation bar with "back" and "next" buttons to "scroll". You see an example of this in the gwt Mail Application example. The example also shows you how to handle the last slice which may have less than X elements (simply making the rows invisible anyway)

--

If you still wanna go for ShowMorePagerPanel, you may want to modify it to implement an actual pager, that is, have some mechanism to only keep in memory the items that you are now displaying (handling scroll events) and maybe to also keep those items before and afterwards the current display to make the scrolling smoother. This is important if memory use is an issue.

Comment: if i keep on calling display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize) , it mean i will get the same elements like previous call and not cached. no i do not want to do page paging like you suggested. i interested to do interface like twitter. so my question is anyway to cache those elements rather than keep on calling display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize)

Comment: My last paragraph after "--" answers your problem; also about the caching which btw Twitter doesn't make. Actually _display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize)_ is just called when the user scrolls further down until the current limit, no when he scrolls up or scrolls down in the middle.